# Gradle 'processTestResources' task not copying files

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle so this question may be silly, but i have a project configured with the 'java' plugin like so:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

and it has a file structure like so:

```
src
`-- test
    |-- java
    |   `-- com/example/Test.java
    `-- resources
        `-- com/example/test.txt
```

When i run `gradlew testClasses` (or `processTestResources` more specifically) the Test.class appears in the build folder but the test.txt does not get copied. am I missing something? my understanding is that this should be standard behaviour. do i need to include it in the CopySpec?

I am running gradle 1.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a brief look at my build directory for the project, I noticed there is a seperate folder for resources apart from classes. So it **is** copying there.

from what I understand the resources folder is available on the classpath at runtime, But I was expecting the physical (meta-physically speaking) file to be in the same directory as the Test.class file in my code. hence my question.